# Craft 2 CP session expires unexpectedly, requires repeated login

Tags: control-panel, admin, session

**Environment**
Craft: 2.6.3013 (Personal)
MAMP Pro: 4.4.1
PHP: 7.0.12 (CGI Mode)

**Behavior**
After logging into the CP, and following a relatively short period of time, the session expires unexpectedly and Craft requests a login. Attempting to log in fails and immediately returns to the login modal; however, simply refreshing the page re-establishes the session, but again for only the limited period of time.

Looking at `/craft/storage/runtime/sessions` I see that Craft is creating a number of sessions, some of them being zero bytes.

**Attempted Solutions**
I've tried the following, based on other users' past experiences and solutions:

- In general.php: `'requireMatchingUserAgentForSession' => false`
- In general.php: `'overridePhpSessionLocation' => true`
- In php.ini: `session.auto_start = 0`
- Permissions set to 777 for `/craft/storage/runtime`
- In MAMP, enable/disable "Xdebug (Debugger)" PHP extension
- Lastly, tested in both PHP 7.0.12 and 5.6.32 without CGI mode

**Next Steps?**
Does it appear that I've missed anything in my previous steps? I've been using Craft 2 for a couple of years in a variety of environments--MAMP 3 / Vagrant / Docker--and haven't experienced this before. The issue isn't a showstopper, but certainly an annoyance, and I would be grateful for thoughts on what to try next.

Comment: This might prove helpful - https://nystudio107.com/blog/the-case-of-the-missing-php-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

This ended up being an issue with, so far as I can tell, my env variables--specifically a misconfiguration with the `basePath`.